# Cheapest (jun 2020) discrete GPU with working powersaving on GNU / Linux multihead

Tags: graphics-cards, linux, multiple-monitors, power

With *working* I mean GNU/Linux temperatures should not exceed Windows' ones by 10 C° with [`low`](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Radeon#Power_consumption_when_using_multi-head_.2F_multi-monitor) performance profile.

Preferably powersaving support over multi monitor configurations should be present into free driver.

Comment: Note that my RX 580 Radeon graphics card does **not** spin up when supporting multiple monitors. If you require discrete graphics without any particular 3D support you could look at NVidia GT 710 which is supported out of the box on Linux, it seems. Those are usually passive cards, so even under load it should not use too much. There is even a newer one with 4 x HDMI output (although the supported resolutions are rather low, it's more for multiple TV sized screens it seems).

Comment: RX 580 is about 200 euro, RX 550 only somewhat below that. Mine sports a "fan stop" option, which you can *configure* in Linux. The GT 710 can be found starting at 40 euro here in NL (!) and the multiple HDMI one should be about 70-80-ish. But I don't have any specific power usage data on it.

Comment: I have a 4-head (1 HDMI + 3 DVI) setup split on two Radeon 5850: on windows I get temperatures up to 55C with all monitors on, while on GNU I get 55C and 60C with 2 (1 monitor per card with `dpm` on) and an astonishing 65C and 72C (with `low` profile since `dpm` does not work when multiple monitors are connected) with everything on. Basically I wanted to be sure to pick up a card that did not suffer from this problem.

Comment: Of course I meant in idle.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've bought an RX 580; I've got mixed feelings about it because it basically doesn't work; displays start to flicker and continuously turn off even when typing in a virtual terminal, so that the system is pretty much unusable. I've checked on the bug tracker and apparently these kind of issues are pretty common with AMD cards; also the driver have complete support for power saving only when used in a single head configuration. So I'm sorry but your advice was definitely very bad.

Comment: On the other hand the card never goes over 30 degrees celsius lol.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've bought an RX 580; I've got mixed feelings about it because it basically doesn't work; displays start to flicker and continuously turn off even when typing in a virtual terminal, so that the system is pretty much unusable. I've checked on the bug tracker and apparently these kind of issues are pretty common with AMD cards; also the driver have complete support for power saving only when used in a single head configuration. So I'm sorry but your advice was definitely very bad. 
PS: at least the card never goes over 35 degrees celsius.

Comment: Sorry to hear, I certainly don't have those issues, so mileage may vary I suppose. When I read them it seems more related to power supply issues than anything else - but other causes cannot be ruled out.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the power supply. As of now I have setup a second 650 watt (52A on 12V line) PSU powering the GPU alone while detaching all other devices from the motherboard and still the same.

Comment: Also before the RX 580 I had an HD 5850 crossfire setup on this motherboard; I haven't cheked but I think it used way more current back the than now.

And last time I turned it on, I was not having this issue at all on Windows.

Comment: It can be any kind of thing. Unfortunately I cannot see the screen, but faulty hardware or bad connections could certainly cause this. I'm not sure if this tale can be brought down to the RX 580 being a bad choice for a setup, but then I don't troubleshoot these kind of problems often. I just did a bit of Googling and I find preciously little.

Comment: Linked to the issue I opened on DRM bug tracker, there's another one from 4 years ago (apparently closed with a workaround and kept open for over 2 years) listing countless AMD gpu models having the same kind of issue. Also, considering in the past I had to wait over 5 years to have a version of the `radeon` driver which didn't put my radeons under 100% load when connected to more than one display, I wouldn't be surprised if AMD is selling GPUs which work poorly on GNU in some non-mainstream setups (like it is a 5 head setup).

Comment: I mean, as of today my old GeForce 8400M chipset still reaches 100C with the Nouveau driver, and there is no proprietary alternative working on modern kernels.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes doubling PSU power solved my problem. thank you again for the magnificent advice, the card is perfect as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After six months of usage I can say
[Maarten Bodewen](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13674/cheapest-jun-2020-discrete-gpu-with-working-powersaving-on-gnu-linux-multihe#comment22734_13674)
suggestion for the Radeon 580RX has been wise.

I wouldn't suggest a PSU with less than 850 watt of power to anyone else going this way, though.

Comment: Depends on your CPU. I have an RX 570 (pretty similar to RX580) and only a 650W PSU. My PSU is really overpowered because my CPU doesn't use so much energy (max 50W)

Comment: A high quality psu is important though

Comment: I was using a 650W PSU, too. same brand